# Does Square payment supports multi-vendor payment?

Tags: payment-gateway, square

I want to integrate square payment gateway for multi-vendor website.

I have done some research on this but not getting the exact answer that Does it providing multi-vendor support or not. Also does it supports, Split payment?

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's correct you'll use [OAuth](https://developer.squareup.com/docs/oauth-api/overview) to connect to other sellers accounts so your application can take actions on their behalf. As for split payments are you looking to collect a fee from each payment? If so you can use `app_fee_money` to [collect a fee](https://developer.squareup.com/docs/payments-api/take-payments-and-collect-fees).

Answer (score -1):

as per the forums You can onboard as many Square merchants as you want to your application using the [OAuth API](https://developer.squareup.com/reference/square/oauth-api). This will enable you to make API calls on behalf of the individual Square merchants, so you can make payments/customers/orders/etc. I’m not sure what you mean by your second question, what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: Hi @Malik, Does it supports split payment?